# Como usar sqlite3 com docker compose

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3, docker

Uma vez que bancos em sqlite3 são apenas arquivos;
E containers, pela sua própria lógica de escalabilidade são criados e excluídos de acordo com a necessidade;
Qual a melhor maneira de trabalhar com ambos em parceria?
Veja bem, estou tentando evitar criar uma nova imagem ou volume pra esse banco, mas honestamente estou aberto a possibilidades.
Fiz uma pergunta relacionada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/364678/como-compartilhar-pastas-com-docker-compose), porém com outro foco.

Sei também que podem existir mil alternativas ao banco escolhido, mas como novo na área, tenho familiaridade e confiança no sqlite3 e gostaria de soluções pra este.

> ----- **Editado** -----

Tenho na pasta do meu app, uma subpasta chamada *volume*.
E gostaria de acessar a pasta */var/www/volumet* do host.
Meu Dockerfile depois da resposta:

```
FROM python:3-alpine

ADD ./var/www/volumet /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk make gcc python3-dev python-dev libxslt-dev libc-dev openssl-dev libffi-dev
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5050

ENV NAME Ibuprofenovar

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Meu docker-compose.yml depois da resposta:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - /var/www/volumet:/volume
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4000:5050"
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa definir um volume no seu arquivo docker-compose que aponte para onde o seu arquivo sqlite esta localizado,

docker-compose.yml
    version: "3"

```
services:
  app:
    restart: on-failure
    build: .
    container_name: myapp
    volumes: 
      - ./code:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
ADD ./code /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python run.py
```

Com o volume definido, os arquivos da pasta code serão espelhados para dentro da pasta app dentro do container. Talvez isso resolva seu problema.

> Edit

https://github.com/LuisMSoares/sqlite-docker-compose

Comment: Bom dia, @LuisEduardo. De acordo com sua resposta, editei minha pergunta, mas ainda sem sucesso

Comment: Você fez o build depois da alteração no docker-compose?

Comment: Sim, mas ele trava no commando ADD e não finaliza o build. Tentei alterar o */var/www/volumet* pra *../../../../www/volumet* mas da forbidden path. Talvez eu esteja ignorando a ideia do docker de utilizar diretórios de dentro do diretório da imagem, mas penso eu que se utilizar dessa maneira, quando atualizar meus arquivos com um git pull por exemplo, ele sobrescreva meu *database* do mesmo jeito.

Comment: sugeri alterações, com o volume criado, você não precisa do Copy, e tambem precisa do . depois do ADD como no meu dockerfile ADD ./code /app

Comment: Sim, mas dessa maneira, com . ele usa o path do meu projeto, né? Não tem como acessar o caminho /var/www do host? No mais, se for impossível, vou fechar minha pergunta aqui mesmo, aceitar e dar como respondida.

Comment: Se o seu dockerfile e o compose esta em uma pasta X e o seu código em uma pasta Y, você precisa colocar ADD ./Y /app, porque e o caminho local + o caminho da pasta q vc quer criar o volume, neste caso a pasta Y, somente os arquivos dentro dela serão espelhados dentro do container. Agora se você quer colocar tudo, basta colocar ADD . /app assim todos os dados locais serão espelhados lá dentro.

Comment: Consegui dessa maneira inserir o banco já criado nos containers, mas não consigo alterar o mesmo, como se o caminho do meu volume não estivesse certo.

Comment: No meu código, me dirijo à pasta */volume* e consigo fazer alterações nela, mas essas alterações não afetam a pasta do meu host, só a do container

Comment: Aqui amigo, isso resolve seu problema. https://github.com/LuisMSoares/sqlite-docker-compose

Comment: Sei que não devo ficar comentando coisas como obrigado ou afins. Mas surgiu um imprevisto aqui que se tornou prioridade, assim que surgir o tempo necessário pra novos testes, faço um novo posicionamento. Provavelmente apagarei esse comentário na sequência. Grato pela resposta e interesse.